# Port is listening, but owned by no one

Tags: macos, port

Preface (skip for the real problem): I have an application that is listening to port 843. This process is run as root. Sometimes killing the process (with ^C) leaves it hanging for a long time (forever?). Being impatient, I kill it with `kill -9`. The problem now is that port 843 is still listening, even though there no application there.

Looking at `lsof -i` shows me no processes listening to 843, even when run as root. Looking at `netstat -a`, however, shows that it is listening, and even some connections that weren't torn down correctly:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp6       0      0  localhost.843          localhost.60927        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6     386      0  localhost.843          localhost.60926        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0  localhost.843          localhost.60925        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6     386      0  localhost.843          localhost.60924        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp46      0      0  *.843                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.843                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

[A similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/orphaned-connections-in-close-wait-state) recommends that I don't get into this situation in the first place. That's sound advice, but a bit hard since it's not my application. Furthermore, it would be nice to be get out of it regardless.

Any way I can get out of this mess without rebooting? Is the fact that I ran it as root important? (I only need root to listen to low-numbered ports, for which I didn't find a way without installing software like authbind).

Comment: could you please post the output of `netstat -lntp|grep 843`

Comment: This is on OSX (BSD), so `-lntp` probably means something other than you want. Specifically, `-p` takes an argument (protocol). What would the output be?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is an equivalent of `-p` in OSX :\