# No idea what is listening on port 80 in OS X

Tags: macos, networking, port-forwarding, port, iptables

I'm on OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.3, and I've freshly rebooted my Mac.

I want to start a service (like Apache on port 80), but there is already something going on with port 80:

```
telnet localhost 80

Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Wait, I hear you say, you can find that with lsof or netstat. Except there is nothing there

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep '\.80'

*comes back blank*

lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN

*comes back blank
```

So from what I know about unix systems, I figure this must be a packet forwarding rule then? I.e. packets are being forwarded from inbound port 80 to something else, which is listening on that service.

```
ipfw show

65535 0 0 allow ip from any to any
```

Hmm, nothing unusual there

```
pfctl -s nat

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

Nothing unusual there

My question is, how can I display any packet forwarding rules... On Linux I might just do iptables -L -t NAT, or iptables -L. Or alternatively, can any OSX experts help me diagnose this problem?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your interesting question, but: what if you point your browser to [http://localhost](http://localhost)?

Comment: The `lsof` grep you used would come back blank; port numbers are mapped to `/etc/services` names.  Try `lsof -i | grep http`...

Comment: Actually, the /etc/services mapping isn't a problem if you use the `-i :port` format, only if you  grep. What will be a problem is that `lsof` needs root privs to see other users' processes, so you should use `sudo lsof -i :80` (and I'd try it without the `grep`, just to make sure...)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the suggestions so far, but hasn't turned up anything - even as root, and without greps, there is nothing listed as actually listening to port 80.

Comment: Did you try `lsof -i :80` while still connected in that Telnet session? And apart from trying [http://localhost/](http://localhost/), maybe typing something at that Telnet prompt reveals something...? (Again, I know: even if you figure it out that way, it would not be the answer to your question...)

Comment: Maybe related: [Port is listening, but owned by no one](http://superuser.com/questions/558323/port-is-listening-but-owned-by-no-one).

Comment: Don't you use skype? By default, skype works on :80

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to run these commands as `root` to show other users' processes, for example:

```
sudo lsof -i ':80'
```

---

Mac OS X includes an Apache web server that can be controlled using `apachectl` as `root`. It's usually started via `launchd`, the corresponding configuration file is `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.apache.httpd.plist`. If it's not this Apache running on port 80, it is probably [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd), Apple's implementation of a daemon manager. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd#launchd):

> When launchd scans through the job plists at boot time it reserves and listens on all of the ports requested by those jobs. If so indicated in the plist by the "OnDemand" key, the daemon is not actually loaded at the time. Rather, launchd will listen on the port, start the daemon when needed, and shut it down when it is not. After a daemon is loaded, launchd will keep track of it and make sure it is running if needed.

Comment: So then I guess my idea was right that `sudo lsof -i ':80'` *might* not actually return anything, unless one runs that *while connected* in the Telnet session? But even without those commands, [http://localhost/](http://localhost/) would probably still have shown some Apache welcome page?

Comment: (I believe your answer is probably the solution; it just doesn't match all comments from the OP.)

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant answer. I've now managed to solve it:

1. There was a mistake in httpd.conf, so sudo apachectl start was not starting apache.
2. But launchd was listening on port 80, ready to forward requests to a non-existent server.
3. However launchd wasn't listening in the conventional sense - that is - the results of sudo lsof -i :80 was blank, likewise for netstat
4. I guess launchd does some magic like xinetd in that it doesn't officially listen on a port, but somehow manages to allow connections to the port by bribing the kernel.

Comment: For me what solved the issue was running `sudo apachectl stop` in the terminal.

Comment: This did not work for me, but this version *did* show what was running (OS High Sierra 10.13.6) `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "80"` from https://superuser.com/questions/984919/can-t-get-nginx-to-work-on-port-80-works-fine-on-any-other-port

Answer (score 11):

Just to make the actual answer clear in case users are searching for this.

1. launchd scans the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` on boot and works out from `org.apache.httpd.plist` that it when apache is started it needs to forward port 80 onto it.
2. `sudo apachectl start` was done
3. However there was a mistake in the `httpd.conf` file meaning apache was not started, although this was not reported via the `apachectl` command.
4. Launchd decided to listen on port 80 as it thought apache was up.
5. But the contents of any HTTP request resulted in an immediate close of the connection.
6. `sudo lsof -i :80`  yielded no answers
7. `sudo netstat -an | grep LISTEN` yielded no answers for port 80
8. there was no information so far as I could tell in any diagnostic tools that showed that port 80 was in-use or listening.
9. fixing apache's httpd.conf and restarting apache successfully so httpd was in the ps table, led HTTP requests to be successful.
10. I was therefore mistaking that I couldn't run apache because there was already something listening on port 80, rather than apache conf itself was the cause

Comment: So what was wrong with httpd.conf?  I'm having this problem now and I'm not sure how to proceed based on your answer here..??

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem with OSX El Capitan and Avast antivirus. `sudo lsof -i ':80'` showed a connection to avast.com.

```
me@destop ~|master$ sudo lsof -i ':80'
Password:
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.avast 7964 root   58u  IPv4 0xc4c1bba31fcc2c7f      0t0  TCP 192.168.100.111:52381->mia04-004.ff.avast.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

I had to

1. uninstall Avast with `/Applications/Uninstall Avast.app`
2. `sudo rm -rf "/Library/Application Support/Avast" "/Applications/Avast Business Security.app" "/Applications/Uninstall Avast.app"`
3. restart

to prevent it from using it port 80.