# Can’t get Nginx to work on port 80. Works fine on any other port

Tags: macos, port, nginx, ps

I’ve just setup Homebrew’s Nginx on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

If I set my Ngnix config like this:

```
listen      127.0.0.1:8080;

listen      127.0.0.1:81;

listen      127.0.0.1:75;
```

It’ll work. But If I put this in there:

```
listen      127.0.0.1:80;
```

It wont. I’ll get connection refused if I go `http://127.0.0.1`

`ps` says Nginx is running, but `netstat -a | grep nginx` or `netstat -a | grep 80` says it isn't.

Running this as root, of course (not that I need that for running on `:8080`

And Mac OS X Firewall’s not running.

Error log doesn’t show this anymore anymore:

```
2015/10/10 17:16:19 [emerg] 23906#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
```

Any ideas? I CAN work with this running on `8080` (curiously, when I run on `8080`, it opens the `80` port and redirects it to `80`).

Comment: This can happen if you have previously installed pow http://pow.cx it adds a pfctl rule that forwards all traffic on port 80 to the pow port. Uninstalling pow fixes the problem. It is possible to get both ngrix and pow running together but it's a little fiddly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebooted OSX. Worked.
I think with linux would be different.

Comment: Sometimes we really should think simple. After 1 hour of problem I saw this and worked :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is as follows:

```
2015/10/10 17:16:19 [emerg] 23906#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
```

That “Address already in use” says it all: Something else on your system is using port 80. Do you have web sharing enabled or perhaps Apache installed and running? The way you can check this is to run `lsof` like this on your system:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "80"
```

That will strictly show you what process might be using port 80. If you are curious to see what other ports are set to “listen” on your Mac OS X system just run this command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P
```

And if you just want to check if port 80 is in use, you can use this variation of the `lsof` command that allows checking this stuff without filtering the output with `grep`:

```
sudo lsof -nPL -iTCP:80
```

Answer (score 0):

On unix based system, like MacOS, You just cannot run services on ports below 1024 without super user privilege. But when you reboot your computer, the nginx service is restarted automatically with super user, so it works.

The following command should solve the issue:

```
sudo brew services restart nginx
```

Comment: Restarting nginx doesn't help on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (I have MacBook Air with M1 Chip):

1. Remove httpd (if you have)
2. Disable apache [link](https://superuser.com/questions/986775/how-can-i-remove-apache2-that-i-have-installed-in-mac-os-x#answer-986792)
3. Install nginx
4. Change port to 80 from `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`